# how to get user data using facebook intigration in windows phone 8.1 winRT?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing facebook integration in my windows phone app.I followed this link

```
http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2014/12/windowsphone-store-81-facebook.html?showComment=1444651733047#c5840217249397198715
```

In my class file:

```
class ContinuationManager
    {
        public void ContinueWith(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (rootFrame == null)
                return;

            switch (args.Kind)
            {
                case ActivationKind.PickFileContinuation:
                    break;
                case ActivationKind.PickFolderContinuation:
                    break;
                case ActivationKind.PickSaveFileContinuation:
                    break;
                case ActivationKind.WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation:
                    var continuator = rootFrame.Content as IWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuable;
                    if (continuator != null)
                        continuator.ContinueWithWebAuthenticationBroker((WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs)args);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

 interface IWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuable
    {
        void ContinueWithWebAuthenticationBroker(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args);
    }
```

in the above code continuator  getting null,so below method not calling

in my main page:

```
 public async void ContinueWithWebAuthenticationBroker(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
        {
            ObjFBHelper.ContinueAuthentication(args);
            if (ObjFBHelper.AccessToken != null)
            {
                fbclient = new Facebook.FacebookClient(ObjFBHelper.AccessToken);

                //Fetch facebook UserProfile:  
                dynamic result = await fbclient.GetTaskAsync("me");
                string id = result.id;
                string email = result.email;
                string FBName = result.name;

                //Format UserProfile:  
                GetUserProfilePicture(id);
                TxtUserProfile.Text = FBName;
                StckPnlProfile_Layout.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                BtnLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                BtnLogout.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                StckPnlProfile_Layout.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
```

Iam successfully login, but I am not getting  user data. I want to get user data.please any one help me.

Comment: What is the data that you receive? Any error statements? What is the value of `result`?

Comment: did you find the solution? i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue here. You should mark the page in your app: '`YourPageName : Page, IWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuable'`

Did the trick for me!